# TTF_RenderText_Solid makes my ram's increase until 2GB and returned NULL

Tags: c++, c, pointers, sdl

I am working with SDL library on C/C++ and
I have this method to write text on a screen:

```
//string, pos.x and pos.y
void writeText(int x, int y, char *str)
{
   SDL_Surface* textSurface;
   SDL_Texture *mTexture;
   SDL_Color textColor = { 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF };
   SDL_Rect src, dst;
   SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = getRenderer();

   textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, str, textColor);
   mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, textSurface);
   src.x = 0; dst.x = x;
   src.y = 0; dst.y = y;
   src.w = dst.w = textSurface->w;
   src.h = dst.h = textSurface->h;
   SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, mTexture, &src, &dst);

}
```

I use this method on main function inside do-while to write player SCORE. That, makes memory increase from 20MB (without this method) to 2024MB (using this method) and then returned "read access violation". I think that the problem is that this method create an object in every do-while iteration, and a memory increase without control.

How can I bypass this?

I am newbie with C pointers, I tried something like this to reuse textSurface without create a new object on every iteration:

```
SDL_Surface textSurfaceCreate() {
    SDL_Surface textSurface;
    return textSurface;
}
```

on Main, call something like

```
SDL_Surface textSurface = textSurfaceCreate();
```

and inside do-while:

```
writeText(SDLSurface* textSurface, int x, int y, char *str);
```

but when I compile, Visual Studio gives me some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you show your errors from Visual Studio?

You have actually provided your own solution. If you make those changes to your original code block, so you aren't creating a new SDL_Texture and SDL_Surface each time this function is called (which I imagine to be once per frame) then you won't experience the massive memory increase. You could simply setup your surface and texture outside of your function, elsewhere and pass them to the function, e.g:

```
SDL_Surface* textSurface = nullptr;
SDL_Texture* mTexture = nullptr;

void writeText(SDL_Surface* surface, SDL_Texture* texture, int x, int y, char *str)
{
   SDL_Color textColor = { 0XFF, 0XFF, 0XFF };
   SDL_Rect src, dst;
   SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = getRenderer();

   surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, str, textColor);
   texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, surface);
   src.x = 0; dst.x = x;
   src.y = 0; dst.y = y;
   src.w = dst.w = surface->w;
   src.h = dst.h = surface->h;
   SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, texture, &src, &dst);
}
```

If you didn't want to do this then you could create and destroy the texture and surface at the end of this function, after your draw call. I believe the function will be something like SDL_DestroySurface() and SDL_DestroyTexture().

Comment: Thanks. I have solved problem partially. I have used SDL_DestroyTexture() and memory increases slowlier than last code. SDL_DestroySurface() does not exist. Can I delete SDL_Surface* with another C/C++ function? Thank you.

Comment: OK I solve it. I have used SDL_FreeSurface() for SDL_Surface*.